# Python: How do I retrieve my updated counter value from another function, inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have this project, in which I have a single counter, which counts throughout the whole program. I have several functions, in which this counter appears. The problem is, how do I get the counter  value from another function?

The situation is pretty much like this. The counter already has a previous value:

```
def function1(counter):
    if logic:
        function2(counter)
    print("...", counter, "...")
    # following code
    # function1 should continue with the updated counter value

def function2(counter):
    while logic1
        if logic2
             counter += 1
```

Et cetera. I hope you understood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Perhaps return the counter from `function2`: `counter = function2(counter)` ?

Comment: eh, what's the problem with `new_counter = function2(counter)`?

Comment: What does the counter actually accomplish?

Comment: @Evert: thanks, that seemed to solve the problem! I thought I had already tried your solution, but I guess I screwed up.

Comment: @John Zwinck: When the counter reaches a certain value, the program eventually quits

Comment: @laike9m: The counter value is used by several functions at different points so I wouldn't like to change the variable's name - it would end up in a gazillion different variable names for the same counter

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all

```
while logic
        if logic
             counter += 1
```

does not make a lot of sense.. the while already tests for the logic, no?

to answer your question, the most obvious way would be for function2 to return the counter, but you could consider using classes and putting the counter as a member value for a more OOP approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The logics are actually different, so I edited the original example code